# Is there a usual style for using C#'s SortedDictionary<Key, Value> when you don't care about the value?

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style, sortedlist, sorteddictionary

I'm using `SortedDictionary<Key, Value>` to store a sorted **list** of `Key`s, but don't care to store the `Value`s. The `Key` has one set of criteria for uniqueness and another for sorting (i.e., the properties that `GetHashValue()` and `Equals(Object obj)` use are different than the ones used by `CompareTo(Key key)`).

I know that it is only storing a reference to the `Value`, so the memory usage is small. In my use case, I'll never need to access the `Value` part of the `KeyValuePair<Key, Value>` stored in the dictionary.

Is there some convention specifying what kind of object to use for `Value` in these cases? I'm currently using the same object for both `Key` and `Value`, that is, the type is `Dictionary<Key, Key>` and the I'm using `.Add(key, key)` to add objects.

The same question applies to `SortedList<Key, Value>`, but I need the insertion performance of `SortedDictionary<Key, Value>` in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Value` is a reference type, storing it would waste from 4 to 8 bytes, depending on whether the process is 32-bit or 64-bit. If `Value` is a value type, it may waste even more.

If you don't need it, you can set `Value` to `Byte`. You can't go lower than 1 byte even with an empty struct. You can set to any value, probably 0 is a good choice.

Ideally, if all you need is a set, you should use a set.

There's a `SortedSet<T>` in .NET 4.0+ which uses a tree internally. In fact, `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` uses `SortedSet<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` internally.

The set counterpart of `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` is a `List<T>`, I guess. You'll just need to use binary search and insert values into sorted positions. Implementing `ISet<T>` should be simple.

Comment: Awesome. I am more fluent in Java, so I'm not quite as knowledgeable of the collections available in C#. In Oracle's documentation, when you look at the documentation for Collection<T> (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), you find a list of "All Known Implementing Classes". Is there something similar in Microsoft's C# documentation? I only just now saw SortedSet<T> barely mentioned at the bottom of Sorted Collection Types (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z658b67.aspx)

Comment: @austinian The list of standard generic collections is pretty short: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.collections.generic.aspx Or if you want the complete list, start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg145035.aspx (specialized collections are rarely used, "object-model collections" are one base, one observable and several read-only ones, this leaves concurrent and generic). There're also immutable collections which are available on NuGet. And that's pretty much it.